# How I can colour the part of SVG image using classname ? (Interacted with jinja and button)

Tags: python, java, svg, button

I have one map from SVG, the countries that have just one territory have one ID (BR), but countries with multi territory have just a class(France). I can color the countries with ID using a button and this:

`onclick="document.getElementById('countryID').style.fill='red'"`

but when try to do the same with class nothing change:

`onclick="document.getElementsByClassName("countryClassname").style.fill='red'"`

Ps.: Im using jinja to put the countryID and country class automatic from my database ''{% for country in camerica %}''. I checked and was going well, but the color don't change just for the class.

Here is a bit of the SVG where Angola have a class and Afghanistan one ID:

```
 <path d="M1383 261.6l1.5 1.8-2.9 0.8-2.4 1.1-5.9 0.8-5.3 1.3-2.4 2.8 1.9 2.7 1.4 3.2-2 2.7 0.8 2.5-0.9 2.3-5.2-0.2 3.1 4.2-3.1 1.7-1.4 3.8 1.1 3.9-1.8 1.8-2.1-0.6-4 0.9-0.2 1.7-4.1 0-2.3 3.7 0.8 5.4-6.6 2.7-3.9-0.6-0.9 1.4-3.4-0.8-5.3 1-9.6-3.3 3.9-5.8-1.1-4.1-4.3-1.1-1.2-4.1-2.7-5.1 1.6-3.5-2.5-1 0.5-4.7 0.6-8 5.9 2.5 3.9-0.9 0.4-2.9 4-0.9 2.6-2-0.2-5.1 4.2-1.3 0.3-2.2 2.9 1.7 1.6 0.2 3 0 4.3 1.4 1.8 0.7 3.4-2 2.1 1.2 0.9-2.9 3.2 0.1 0.6-0.9-0.2-2.6 1.7-2.2 3.3 1.4-0.1 2 1.7 0.3 0.9 5.4 2.7 2.1 1.5-1.4 2.2-0.6 2.5-2.9 3.8 0.5 5.4 0z" id="AF" name="Afghanistan">
 </path>
 <path class="Angola" d="M 1121.2 572 1121.8 574 1121.1 577.1 1122 580.1 1121.1 582.5 1121.5 584.7 1109.8 584.6 1109 605.1 1112.6 610.3 1116.2 614.3 1105.8 616.9 1092.3 616 1088.5 613 1065.8 613.2 1065 613.7 1061.7 610.8 1058.1 610.6 1054.7 611.7 1052 612.9 1051.5 608.9 1052.4 603.2 1054.4 597.3 1054.7 594.6 1056.6 588.8 1058 586.2 1061.3 582 1063.2 579.1 1063.8 574.4 1063.5 570.7 1061.9 568.4 1060.4 564.5 1059.1 560.7 1059.4 559.3 1061.1 556.8 1059.5 550.6 1058.3 546.3 1055.5 542.2 1056.1 541 1058.4 540.1 1060.1 540.2 1062.1 539.5 1078.8 539.6 1080.1 544.3 1081.7 548.2 1083 550.3 1085.1 553.6 1088.9 553.1 1090.7 552.2 1093.8 553.1 1094.7 551.5 1096.2 547.8 1099.7 547.5 1100 546.4 1102.9 546.4 1102.4 548.7 1109.2 548.6 1109.3 552.7 1110.4 555.1 1109.5 559 1109.9 563 1111.7 565.4 1111.3 573 1112.7 572.4 1115.1 572.6 1118.6 571.6 1121.2 572 Z">
 </path>
 <path class="Angola" d="M 1055.3 539 1053.8 534.2 1056.1 531.4 1057.8 530.3 1059.9 532.5 1057.9 533.9 1056.9 535.5 1056.7 538.3 1055.3 539 Z">
 </path>

Thanks!!
```

Comment: getElementsByClassName returns multiple elements. You can loop throught them.

Comment: [MDN getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)